# Github ruleset fails incorrectly

Tags: regex, github, github-rulesets

I'm setting a ruleset on my repository that follows [this example](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/creating-rulesets-for-a-repository#enforce-conventional-commits).

The rule applies to my `master` branch. I'm not able to merge any branch to it and I'm getting the following error:

> **Merging is blocked**
>
> Commit message must start with a matching pattern:
> ^(build|chore|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|revert|style|test){1}(([\w-.]+))?(!)?:
> ([\w ])+([\s\S]*)

I've created a sample branch with a single commit with this message: `chore(myfeature): added empty file`, and I'm still getting this error.

I would note that this is a fairly old repo and I'm assuming that there are commits on `master` that don't follow this convention, but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Any ideas as to why this happens or how can we fix this?

Comment: There is a match for the pattern and the string, see https://regex101.com/r/XSnaLS/1 Are you sure that the pattern mentioned in the comment `Commit message must start with a matching pattern` is also the same pattern that is used?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, but we should have configured it to match the whole pattern. See my response

Answer (score 1):

It seems we misconfigured the ruleset.

We set it to "Must start with the matching pattern", and we should have set it to "Must match a given regex pattern"